# Distinction of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a set versus that of a vector space

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I know a differentiable manifold first of all is a set, then a topological space, then i give a smooth atlas.

Say the set is $R^2$, then i give the ordinary topology on $R^2$ and then i give an atlas with one chart so $A=\{(R^2,i_d)\}$, $i_d: R^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ the identity map.

I want your validation on something:

$R^2$, before i give the topology, is considered to be only a set, so i cant possibly say $(1,1)+(1,2)=(2,3)$, cause such an operation is not defined!
The only thing i can say is that $R^2$ is an uncountable set!

On the other hand, the target set of the identity map, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is considered to be a vector space (or i can think it as a group the important is that it has more structure than that of a set) so i can do everything i use to do there, i.e. $(1,1)+(1,2)=(2,3)$!

(This is why i did the notational distinction $R^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ for the case of a set and that of a field, respectively.)

Is all this correct?

Thank you

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a field, it is a vector space. The underlying field of the vector space is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To add to Joppy's comment, the fact that there's an addition on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not really related to it's structure as a smooth manifold, until you think of it as a Lie group.

Comment: my point is the target of the identity map has more structure than a set, say its a vector space if you want to.